# Rbenv and two versions of the Heroku client

Tags: ruby, heroku, rubygems, zsh, rbenv

I've got a fairly pesky problem I can't seem to get to the bottom of. I just switched from rvm to rbenv, and now I'm having a problem with the Heroku client.

Basically, there's an old version of Heroku living somewhere in the system and rbenv is not aware of it, but it is overriding any newer version of the heroku client I install. This is a problem because I need the new version of the heroku cli to run cedar commands...

Here's and example from my shell of what's going on:

```
~  » gem uninstall heroku
INFO:  gem "heroku" is not installed
~  » which heroku
heroku: aliased to nocorrect heroku
~  » rbenv which heroku
rbenv: heroku: command not found
~  » gem install heroku  
Fetching: heroku-2.17.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed heroku-2.17.0
1 gem installed
~  » which heroku
heroku: aliased to nocorrect heroku
~  » heroku version
heroku-gem/1.12.1
~  » rbenv which heroku
/Users/Andrew/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/bin/heroku
~  » gem list heroku

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

heroku (2.17.0)
~  » heroku version
heroku-gem/1.12.1
~  »
```

I don't know where the old version of Heroku is, how to get rid of it, or (most importantly) why it is lingering in my system and overriding the rbenv-specific newer gem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you fully remove rvm from your machine before installing rbenv?

Comment: Yes. But, if you have a hunch about some trace that might be left and could be causing the problem, I'd love to check and see...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, it took me a while but I was able to track this down. It turns out that I had used the heroku gem a long time ago (before I was even using RVM), and while RVM had been hiding the old gem, RBENV did not. I found this using:

```
sudo find / -type d -name "*heroku*"
```

This revealed that I had some old gems living in the system ruby folder:

```
Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/...
```

I cleaned out all the subfolders under that, and that fixed my problem.